# Azure deployment slot not updating with new code from VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment-slots

I have a deployment slot demo that I want to update with the new application.  Both Azure and VSTS confirm the release to the slot was successful. Via the Continous Delivery tab and the Release page respectively.  However, when I click on the URL of the deployment slot I am taken to the old application.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the detail build and release log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Thank you for the response.  I am looking at the slot URL today and it seems like it has updated.