# VSTS Continous Delivery without swaping slots

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have configured VSTS Continuous Delivery and it works fine. However I noticed that it also swaps the slots from staging to production even though I have disabled auto swap.

In CI configuration I couldn't find a setting which ask it to perform the swap.

What I want is the CI job to perform the standard tasks and then just send status emails. Swapping the slots has to happen manually.

How can I get this done?

A close [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395014/azure-deployment-slot-not-updating-with-new-code-from-vsts) is not yet answered.

Comment: Which task did you use to deploy the files to Azure?

Comment: Could you share the detail build and release logs? (set system.debug variable to true)

Comment: I got this sorted. Actually I looked at the wrong place for the slot swapping task. Under release pipeline it is there. So I disabled it and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this sorted. Actually I looked at the wrong place for the slot swapping task. Under release pipeline "Swap Slot" task is available. I disabled it and now everything is fine.